# Location of temporary files in OpenCPU Single-User Server

Tags: r, opencpu

I'm beginning to explore OpenCPU via the single-user server on OS X Mavericks, and was wondering where the temporary files are stored. For example, if I run

```
curl http://localhost:9344/ocpu/library/stats/R/rnorm/ --data n=50
```

I get notification that the output is available here:

```
/ocpu/tmp/x0757cc5bd3/R/.val
```

Which I can view if I direct my browser here:

```
http://localhost:9344/ocpu/tmp/x0757cc5bd3/R/.val/print
```

My question is, where is /ocpu/tmp on my machine? There is nothing in my /tmp folder that appears to correspond to the above. Any help/guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The web server running OpenCPU will map the site root (`http://localhost:9344/ocpu`) to a real location on disk.

Comment: It's that real location I'm after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've stumbled upon the answer after incorrectly typing a URL into my browser. The local OpenCPU server maps my temp files onto the following temporary directory:

`/private/var/folders/__/yz_l30s48xj6m_0059b_2twr0000gn/T/ocpu-alexioannides/tmp_library/[your_session_id]`

Answer (score 0):

In your R console (where you have called `library(opencpu)`) execute the function `tempdir()`, you will see the directory in which the temp files are stored.